# What setting allows a PHP to run for more than 60 seconds under Windows FastCGI?

Tags: php, windows, load-time

I have a PHP script which is timing out after 60 seconds. I have changed the following config values but they don't seem to have any affect:

- max_execution_time
- default_socket_timeout
- mysql.connect_timeout
- max_input_time

All of the above have values of 6000, but the script stops after 60 seconds. Can anyone suggest any other reasons the script would terminate?

Comment: You could start it via the commandline. The timelimit will not be a problem then: `php loction/to/file.php`

Answer (score 1):

Check your server's apache and php logs for any error. It might help you to narrow down your problem.

Besides PHP timeouts, there are also other timeouts in Apache and MySQL which might be causing your script to stop working after 60 seconds,

1. `FcgidIOTimeout` and `FcgidBusyTimeout` (file: fcgid.conf) 
   [Ref: premature end of script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15931470/4381432)
2. `connect-timeout` of mysqld server (file:my.cnf) 
   [Ref: mysql connection timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14726944/4381432)
3. `Timeout` of apache server 
   [Ref: Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#TimeOut)

also check [apache and php - limits and timeouts](http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/apache-and-php-limits-and-timeouts) for more details